# C++ STL Algorithms upper_bound() that is not strictly greater

Tags: c++, binary-search, upperbound

Unlike lower_bound, upper_bound does not return an iterator to the element if it compares equivalent to value, but only if it compares strictly greater.

Is there an alternative if I want an upper_bound algorithm that is greater than or equal to.

Comment: -1 the question is not clear. you say you want greater than or equal to.  do you mean the first item greater or equal to the value you give?  or the last item greater or equal to the value you give? or *any* item greater or equal to the value you give?  these functions' names and contracts are already extremely confusing so please be very precise about what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could decrease the iterator by 1.

```
auto begin = ...;
auto end = ...;
auto it = std::upper_bound(begin, end, target);
if (it == begin)
  return it;
-- it;
if (*it < target)
  return ++it;
else
  return it;
```

The position of the iterator will be like this, assume you are searching for 2:

```
1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
      ^     ^ ^
      lb    | ub
            this function


1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3
        ^
        lb & ub & this function
```

Comment: Can't you just use `lower_bound()`?

Comment: Was hoping there would be something already built into STL but this is not a bad alternative.

Comment: @quasiverse: It is different from `lower_bound()` when there are multiple appearances of the target (i.e. when `std::equal_range()` does not return an empty range). See the updated figure.

Comment: @KennyTM In that case can't you use `lower_bound()` with a reversed comparator function?

Comment: @quasiverse: It can't, because in that case the array will not be sorted according to `<`.

Comment: ... hmm... okay, maybe you can do some trippy stuff with reverse itera... okay, +1 ;)

Answer (score 2):

Despite the confusing name, `std::lower_bound` actually does exactly what you want.

> Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the range [first,
> last) that does not satisfy element < value (or comp(element, value)),
> (i.e. greater or equal to), or last if no such element is found.
> https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound

```
std::set<int> s {0, 1, 3};
std::cout << s.lower_bound(2); // yields 3
std::cout << s.lower_bound(1); // yields 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this using option (2)

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound?force_isolation=true

Assuming you know your data type (int in this case, but you could easily template this):

```cpp
std::upper_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), target,
                 [](const int &a, const int &b) { return a <= b; });
```